# Building packages to yocto image (image) without using recipes

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, yocto

I am a newbie to yocto. Have worked on its basics for few weeks and now I have the task of installing few packages on to the yocto image (poky) and I'm completely stuck and don't know what to do.

The procedure I am following is :
I have cloned the packages from github on to my host machine and put inside a directory.
Now in poky I have deb , apt-get working.
But how do I install these cloned packages .
I do not want to follow the recipe /layers method.
The packages i want to put is : numpy, tensor flow, pyserial, h5py.

Comment: Be aware Debian .deb packages are not compatible with Yocto .deb packages, so you need to create those packages with recipes.

Comment: @Nayfe But we can enable deb packages right?  I mean set the Deb packages in local config file ?

Comment: You can use Yocto deb packages by setting `PACKAGE_CLASSES = "package_deb"` and `IMAGE_FEATURES_append = " package-management"` in `local.conf`

Comment: And this thing is only for yocto related deb packages or for all type of deb packages I mean as you mentioned in the first comment,doeses the configuration set in 3rd comment also suite to Debian deb packages?

Comment: Imagine I have cloned tensorflow from github on my host machine, now how can I install that cloned package to yocto image?

Comment: Nop, there is no support for Debian packages. If you want to add tensorflow to Yocto image, you'll need to create a recipe for it. You can look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CiD7rB35CRE). For numpy and pyserial, you can it with following statement in local.conf: `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python3-numpy python3-pyserial "`. I can't see any tensorflow nor h5py existing recipes.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the inputs. I'll work on it.

Comment: Can the above line of code be included anywhere in the local.config file?

Comment: yes, it can be set anywhere in local.conf

Comment: just placing that one line of code is enough or should i also add something to bblayers.conf file?

Comment: You can see in this [website](http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/recipes/) that those recipes are in oe-core, so you don't need to add extra layers, Poky is enough.

Comment: Yea. I had a glance at them. But being in oe-core doesn't mean they can be usable in Poky right? Or can it be without any additional add-on..?

Comment: Yes, everything in oe-core should work in Poky without anything else to do.

Comment: IMAGE_FEATURES_append = " package-management" : this line of code is not required for core-image-sato right ? and should '=' be prefixed with '+' symbol?

Comment: You have been of great help to me throughout, can I please have you email id?

Comment: Indeed, package-management is already set in core-image-sato recipe. You can add stuff to bitbake variables with `VAR += "somestuff"` or `VAR_append = " somestuff"`. It is explained in bitbake manual. mail (vincent . prince . fr @ gmail . com)

Comment: Can i install tensorflow and h5py (since they are not there as recipes) using Internet on yocto? (i mean just the way they are done on ubuntu)...?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can generate a SDK or eSDK for the image that you use, and with that manually build and deploy to the target. Yet while his is technically possible, it has a lot of downsides:

- you are working around package management
- what you do is totally unreproductible
- you will run into lots and lots of problems to fix manually that using the correct mechanism would spare you from, as it already tackles those properly. Especially when compilation is necessary, there are a lot of pitfalls.

You can find the respective documentation here:
https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.4.2/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#sdk-using-the-standard-sdk and https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.4.2/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#sdk-extensible

So in a nutshell: the real point of Yocto/OpenEmbedded is exactly the recipes/metadata mechanisms that you want to not use. If that is a hard requirement for whatever reason (not just "hey I don't like writing recipes"), then the Yocto Project technology is not a good fit for what you need. If you actually want debian-style package management, why not just use debian? Nothing wrong with that, if it fits your usecase.

Comment: I am a bit confused, like: to which are you referring to a technically possible? is it to the method which i have asked i.e. without using recipe ...? According to your last paragraph If recipes is not the exact mechanism then which is? In the last line are you suggesting to you Debian packages in yocto image?

Comment: Yocto SDK gives you cross-compilators, so you can build by hand some sourcecode, then add binaries to the image. Yocto is not the only possible embedded build system, and LetoThe2nd suggests you to pickup another system if you don't like recipes system. For instance, Builldroot is much easier to get into.

Comment: @Nayfe i am fine with the recipe method but i'd like to know how to build packages using source code?

Comment: I understood the cross compiling part.. so now coming to build root, do you mean to say we have to use builtroot in place of yocto? Or we need to use builtroot to build package?

Comment: Did you look at this video on [devtool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CiD7rB35CRE)? It is the recommanded way to create recipes, to support new packages. [Buildroot](https://buildroot.org/) is an alternative to Yocto. By the way, what is your target machine? You can also join #Yocto channel on [irc](https://webchat.freenode.net/).

Comment: Do know how to add keras and tensor flow packages? There are no recipes of them too

Comment: You have to create their recipes.